# How do I pass a URL with multiple parameters into a URL?

Tags: javascript, html, query-string

Basically I'm trying to pass a URL like this:

```
www.foobar.com/?first=1&second=12&third=5
```

into a URL like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?&t=FOOBAR&u=http://www.foobar.com/first=12&amp;sec=25&amp;position=2
```

It only recognizes the first parameter. I'm having the same problem with LinkedIn and Twitter sharing, so it must be something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Rather than `html encoding` your URL parameter, you need to `URL encode` it:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?&t=FOOBAR&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2F%3Ffirst%3D12%26sec%3D25%26position%3D
```

You can do this easily in most languages - [in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript):

```
var encodedParam = encodeURIComponent('www.foobar.com/?first=1&second=12&third=5');
// encodedParam = 'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2F%3Ffirst%3D12%26sec%3D25%26position%3D'
```

(there are equivalent methods in other languages too)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to encode each param in the query string as well in case it had funky characters?

Comment: In my answer, I have assumed that the value for the URL is already valid / properly constructed before you encode it to pass as a param. The method above will work fine even if the URL is not valid - but of course you may not be able to use it effectively at the other end if it’s not

Answer (score 13):

You are missing the `?` in the second URL (Also, it should be URL-encoded to be `%3F`).

Also, I believe that the remaining `&` need to be URL, not HTML-encoded.  Change `&second=12&third=5` to `%26second=12%26third=5` and everything should just work.

This:

```
&u=http://www.foobar.com/first=12&amp;sec=25&amp;position=2
```

should be:

```
&u=http://www.foobar.com/%3Ffirst=12%26sec=25%26position=2
```

Comment: Also may need to encode the colon and forward slashes in the URL.

Comment: @DormoTheNord -- `%31` was a mistake ... should have been `%3F`.

Comment: @Ferdinand - I think you want `encodeURIComponent`, which encodes all URL characters.  `encodeURI` doesn't encode characters such as : and /.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo. I'm using encodeURIComponent

Comment: @justkt: Yes, you are right.  Actually, I meant `escape()` instead of `encode()`, but `encodeURIComponent()` might be better.

Answer (score 2):

In your example parts of your passed-in URL are not URL encoded (for example the colon should be %3A, the forward slashes should be %2F).  It looks like you have encoded the parameters to your parameter URL, but not the parameter URL itself.  Try encoding it as well.  You can use `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you can use:

```
let myObject = {first:1, second:12, third:5};
jQuery.param(myObject);
```

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ 
The output: first=1&second=12&third=5
This will format it, whatever your object contain.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're having issues with the social share links. I had a similar issue at some point and found this question, but I don't see a complete answer for it.
I hope my javascript resolution from below will help:

I had default sharing links that needed to be modified so that the URL that's being shared will have additional UTM parameters concatenated.

My example will be for the Facebook social share link, but it works for all the possible social sharing network links:

The URL that needed to be shared was:

```
https://mywebsitesite.com/blog/post-name
```

The default sharing link looked like:

```
$facebook_default = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2mywebsitesite.com%2Fblog%2Fpost-name%2F&t=hello"
```

I first DECODED it:

```
console.log( decodeURIComponent($facebook_default) );
=>
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://mywebsitesite.com/blog/post-name/&t=hello
```

Then I replaced the URL with the encoded new URL (with the UTM parameters concatenated):

```
console.log( decodeURIComponent($facebook_default).replace( window.location.href, encodeURIComponent(window.location.href+'?utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook')) );

=>

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%mywebsitesite.com%2Fblog%2Fpost-name%2F%3Futm_medium%3Dsocial%26utm_source%3Dfacebook&t=2018
```

That's it!

**Complete solution:**

> $facebook_default = $('a.facebook_default_link').attr('href');
>
> $('a.facebook_default_link').attr( 'href', decodeURIComponent($facebook_default).replace( window.location.href, encodeURIComponent(window.location.href+'?utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook')) );

Answer (score -7):

You have to escape the & character. Turn your

```
&
```

into

```
&amp;
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Web servers don't know HTML entities, the character has to be URI-encoded instead.

Comment: I tried &amps; and it didn't work. I needed %31. Now I'm just using Javascript's encode() function. ^_^

Comment: The entity is called &amp;, not &amps; -- he was pluralizing it for English purposes.. ;)  I edited to be clearer.  But the %31 is better anyway.

Comment: Actually it should be %26 to escape &.

Comment: Maybe it's time to delete this answer :)