# How to create a short url for sharing on social media

Tags: php, url-shortener

I'm trying to write some code which shares a page on Facebook and twitter.
The problem I'm facing is that the page I'm trying to share has a big query string like:

```
http://domain.com/see.php?c=3&a=123&v=1
```

But it seems that Facebook and Twitter don't like that big query string.

I also tried using tiny url with following method in which I passed the URL to a PHP function to get the tiny URL:

```
var a = $("#Link").val();
```

I get the correct value of `**a**`. After that I pass this value to a PHP file:

```
$.post("ShortLink.php?value="+a
```

In that PHP file I got the following value:

```
http://domain.com/see.php?c=3
```

All the values after `3` is deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `POST`ing to your `ShortLink.php` file, you should make sure to URL encode the value of `a` beforehand. Otherwise you're calling `ShortLink.php?value=http://domain.com/see.php?c=3&a=123&v=1`, i.e., sending:

```
value = http://domain.com/see.php?c=3
a = 123
v = 1
```

What you want is `ShortLink.php?value=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fsee.php%3Fc%3D3%26a%3D123%26v%3D1`, thus sending:

```
value = http://domain.com/see.php?c=3&a=123&v=1
```

This can be achieved via [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
$.post("ShortLink.php?value=" + encodeURIComponent(a));
```

See also [*How do I pass a URL with multiple parameters into a URL?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095887/how-do-i-pass-a-url-with-multiple-parameters-into-a-url) and [*How to encode a URL in Javascript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u just use an url shortener API for that, like [Google url shortener](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/urlshortener/). That way, you can leave your code the way it is, but for site's like Facebook and Twitter, it is nicely short.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.post("ShortLink.php?value=" + escape(a));
```